# Factory reset not working on Galaxy 10.1 tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, 3.1-honeycomb

I have a galaxy tab with following specs

```
Model number: GT-P7510
Android version: 3.1
Kernel version 2.6.36.3 se.infra@sep-58#1
Build number: HMj37.UEKF3 P7510UEKF3
```

I have tried

```
-- Settings > Privacy > Factory reset
-- Powered off the device -> Up Key + Power button -> Recovery mode > Factory reset
```

, but its not resetting the tab to factory settings, After restarting its always showing me already installed applications and gmail/facebook account.

Comment: Depends on your definition. "soft reset" would be a forced shutdown of the device, and nothing is reset. "hard reset" is forcing a restart by removing the power source -- which again doesn't reset anything. Have you tried a factory-reset (either via the *Settings* menu, or via booting into recovery)?

Comment: I misunderstood the soft/hard reset defination. Question is updated now

Comment: That's a common mistake, so no need to be ashamed :) We have too many ambiguous terms, and manufacturers are also adding to that (calling something "fast boot" when there's already "fastboot" [not related at all], to give one example). // Thanks for your update. Now I'm really confused: A factory-reset is supposed to remove all user-data and user-installed apps, so your accounts should have been gone. Unless they got restored by Google's Cloud Backup when you re-established your Google account. Can you confirm that? Did you have to setup your Google account after the factory-reset?

Comment: Yes, its looking that it is restoring it after reset, but not sure how to prevent it. I got it from my friend and not able to remove his account/apps :(

Comment: Oh -- that's strange. You wouldn't have setup his account -- but a factory-reset should have removed it. If you have [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) available via your computer, you could try to wipe the device using `fastboot -w`. Flashing a different ROM *might* solve it (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)). Can you ask your friend what modifications he might have applied? He's not playing games with you, is he?